# checking if a string has special characters

Tags: java, regex

how would i check a string for special characters such as $%#, and numbers?
I only want chars, ex abcd.

the only method i can think of is to make an arraylist of the alphabet and check each index to see if it is in the arraylist.

thanks

Answer (score 10):

RegEx is probably your best bet:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(sourceString);
 boolean b = m.matches();
```

Comment: You could also shorten it by calling sourceSting.matches("[a-zA-Z]")

Comment: @Zach - ... at the cost of recompiling the pattern each time you do it.  (Admittedly, @lukiffer's code doesn't hoist the pattern creation.)

Answer (score 1):

you can try a regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]");
if(p.matcher(string).find()){
//something is not a letter
}
```